# C# listview - embedding controls

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Can anybody help me with embedding controls in the listview. I need to add button controls as subitem of listview. thanks

Comment: fyi this is quite difficult... you'd be better off finding a replacement listview control that does what you need.

Comment: Is this winfroms listview or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could be talking about the Windows Forms [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx), in which case you're pretty much SOL (sh*t outta luck.) You can custom draw on the ListView but even that has limitations in Windows Forms.

Or you could be talking about the Windows Presentation Foundation [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx). In this case it's really quite simple. You can create a DataTemplate that you associate with the ListView's columnn. [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972.aspx).

Or finally you could be talking about the ASP.NET [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) control which also has data templating support but the implementation is a bit different from WPF. [Here's an example of that.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) control which is opensource. It is excellent and is derived from ListView in Window.Forms.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express). It is free and allows custom embedded controls:

[image]

[Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) has been created to fix known issues of the regular .NET ListView and solve common issues such as this one out of the box.

Comment: Is it trial version free for limited time?

Comment: @NitinSawant The trial version is unlimited, you can evaluate it as long as you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use another control instead of a listview, try the DataGridView - you can add any type of control to a cell (subitem).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx