# Visual objects that change size in c# displayed in a linear list

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

Please forgive any silly words I may say. I am coming from a Actionscript3 background.

I am using "Visual C# 2010 Express".
I have a simple Form, `in a WindowsForm Project`, which currently holds just a Listbox. (Which I presume I will have to change to something else).

And I made myself a different display object (User Control) that is currently a Checkbox a title. (More will be added once I get over the hurdle below)

But I can't even get as far as Displaying the UserControl as a list.
I can't seem to find anywhere on the listbox to say "User this displayobject as the visual for listbox". I see tutorials saying "ItemsPanelTemplate" but I get error saying there is no such property for a Listbox.
I even tried making the Form in Design view and it is not in the list down the side of the GUI when I dragged as Listbox on screen.

Now I know how I would do this in pure Actionscript, but I dont know how to do this in Pure C#. Tutorials are not helping, as all the Microsoft site seems to try to give me is XAML (XML). and I am looking for C# code. So I have thrown in the towel and pleading for outside help.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Is this is WindowsForms project ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, forgot to mention that. I'l add it.

Comment: Are you required to use WinForms? WPF (=XAML) would make such stuff MUCH easier...

Comment: I dont like XML to be used for code. Would prefer a real code way please.

Comment: Then you need to stop reading WPF books and tutorials and use the Winforms way.  Use a ListBox or ListView with View = List.

Comment: I have been trying to NOT read WPF, but its all google is finding. :(.. I am trying to use ListBox. Its HOW which I am requesting help on. I will look into ListView. Thank you.

Comment: @WORMSS => WinForms does not give you access to the control  template, so you will not be able to adjust the Items Panel.  It's a WPF thing.  If you need to Google on legacy technology, try adding 'WinForms' to your search criteria...

Comment: I am already way ahead of you. I see many places asking, noone with an answer. This is why I am asking here. I am thinking I might just scrap the whole project and build it in Adobe Air. That lets you do anything you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a list of items, each with a CheckBox and some descriptive text. Try using the `CheckedListBox` control. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ss05xx6.aspx).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472897/c-sharp-can-i-display-images-in-a-list-box) also answers the question of how to do custom image drawing for each item in a ListBox. It may be helpful.

**Edit after clarification:**

Try embedding the UserControl in a ListView, rather than a ListBox.
References on embedding controls in ListViews:

[C# listview - embedding controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054840/c-sharp-listview-embedding-controls)

[Adding button into a Listview in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456063/adding-button-into-a-listview-in-winforms)

You could also use a list of Panels, with each Panel hosting a UserControl.

[C# List of Panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163634/c-sharp-list-of-panels)

But the real answer, as seen in the question's comments, is that Winforms doesn't have a convenient way to do this. This is a task much better suited to WPF.

Comment: You didn't read `(More will be added once I get over the hurdle below)`

Comment: I am making a user control, `it currently only has a checkbox and title`, it WILL have buttons, more checkboxes, groups, expandable sections. But since I couldn't even get a simple usercontrol to show yet, there was no point in making the complicated bit. I just want to give the Listbox a reference to the class or something, and then say for ever piece of data in a list, make a new object of that class and give it the data. It just seems so overly complicated.

Comment: Thank you. I have looked into the WPF, and again, I could not find a way to easily tell a simple list that the object to use is a certain class. I was getting stopped by my lack of understanding the tutorials. I have changed language completely and going to use Adobe Air. It can be done as simply as ListComponent.displayClass = myCustomClass. Thank you for all your help Eso. I have given you a +1 and Answer for all your trouble.

Comment: Cheers. Thank you also for clarifying what you were trying to do, sorry I didn't understand at first.

Answer (score 0):

You may check out freeware component [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) from ComponentOwl. It supports simple Details view without columns, two and three-state checkboxes, images and more...

They also offers full version with even more nice features like hierarchical and multi-line items.